# Unable to update hikari datasource configuration in spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

Hikari datasource configurations always taking as default values. even though i provide the actual configurations in application.yml file.

**MainApp.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

//I use below method to set password from different approach instead of taking from app.yml
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    DataSource ds = properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
     .password("setting a password from vault")
     .build();
    return ds;
}
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: demo
  datasource:
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 20000
      minimum-idle: 5
      maximum-pool-size: 12
      idle-timeout: 300000
      max-lifetime: 1200000
      auto-commit: true
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://ip:port;databaseName=sample
    username: username
```

Using Spring 2.1.1.RELEASE and when i start the application i logged the Hikari logs and it says all default values. So i did debugged on the second bean datasource and its actually HikariDatasource and except default values rest of them are empty and not reflecting the given values from the application.yml. Please recommend or comment if i misconfigured anything or done any mistake!

Comment: You manually configured everything so your settings are useless. Use the defaults if you want them to apply. Apparently your password comes from else where, then create a `Propertysource` that integrates with that environment. If you are using the Hashicorp Vault there is support already for that without you having to configure any thing manually (apart from the vault connection ofcourse).

Comment: Yes right Deinum, i have removed the java configuration and passed the password runtime and it accepting my changes from app.yml. and i then created an own HikariDatasource bean and set values from app.yml using env variables. Thanks it helps.

Comment: You don't need to create your own datasource, Spring Boot already does that for you.

Comment: Yes. The data source which is been created automatically will not have all the connection configurations like password and stuff because those had to be get from other source. So tats y created a bean and in that bean am setting required params...

Comment: Is there a way to acquire the auto configured data source in application main class and then set password to it??

Comment: As mentioned, don't. Create a `PropertySource` for that, register that with the `Environment`  and let Spring Boot do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Requirement is to get password from the own custom vault implement which is written in Java. Is there a way or code snippets or ideas for this approach.. I tried jsypt and auto configurations works like charm. But the requirement is this so..

Comment: Write your own `PropertySource` which delegates that to your vault. You already have code to obtain the stuff from the vault, that code needs to go into a `PropertySource`.